# replace elements with a pattern in a dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have one data frame similar to:

```
df1 = read.table(text="name element
    m20895  P540554
    m20897  S01367
    m20907  P540554,P209332
    m20914  S01367,S01247
    m20915  S01247
    m20925  S00897
    m26943  P540554,P209332
    m26944  S00897,S00898,S00899,S00900", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to replace any element(s) starting with "S" by the corresponding value in the "B" column of data frame (df2)

```
    df2 = read.table(text="A    B
    S01367  P00432
    S01247  P00433
    S00897  P00434
    S00898  P00435
    S00899  P00436
    S00900  P00437
    S00901  P00438", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

so the result expected:

```
    result = read.table(text="name  element
    m20895  P540554
    m20897  P00432
    m20907  P540554,P209332
    m20914  P00432,P00433
    m20915  P00433
    m20925  P00434
    m26943  P540554,P209332
    m26944  P00434,P00435,P00436,P00437", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: I would suggest that you move away from storing your data in unnormalized CSV format as you are doing.  It will make working with your data much more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to split your `element` column by `,`:

```
element_split <- strsplit(df1$element, ",")
```

You obtain a list and, for each element of this list, you can look for item beginning with `S` (`grep("^S", ...)`) and replace them with the corresponding `B` value in your `df2` (if there is none, then you just return the item as is):

```
l_element_B <- lapply(element_split, 
                      function(x) if(any(y <- grep("^S", x))) {x[y] <- df2$B[match(x[y], df2$A)]; x} else x)
```

Then you can collapse your elements with `,` to get your new column (or keep it as list to make it easier to work with):

```
df1$new_element <- sapply(l_element_B, paste, collapse=",")

df1
#    name                     element                 new_element
#1 m20895                     P540554                     P540554
#2 m20897                      S01367                      P00432
#3 m20907             P540554,P209332             P540554,P209332
#4 m20914               S01367,S01247               P00432,P00433
#5 m20915                      S01247                      P00433
#6 m20925                      S00897                      P00434
#7 m26943             P540554,P209332             P540554,P209332
#8 m26944 S00897,S00898,S00899,S00900 P00434,P00435,P00436,P00437
```

---

**N.B:**

Of course you can directly modify your column by doing

```
df1$element <- sapply(l_element_B, paste, collapse=",")
```

instead of

```
df1$new_element <- sapply(l_element_B, paste, collapse=",")
```

Comment: Nice! Very elegant. Didn't realize you can assign within an if call.

Comment: If any value of column "element" in df1 is a mixture of elements starting with "P" and "S". this code will drop the "P" element. For example, in row 4, suppose the value is "P01367,S01247". it only gave one replaced element.

Comment: @user3354212 indeed, small bug (it was missing returning the whole x element), I fixed it, can you confirm it works as expected now?

Comment: @iod you can assign pretty much anywhere you want to ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(element) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by=c("element" = "A")) %>% 
  mutate(element = ifelse(is.na(B), element, B)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(element= paste(element, collapse = ","))  
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  name   element                    
  <chr>  <chr>                      
1 m20895 P540554                    
2 m20897 P00432                     
3 m20907 P540554,P209332            
4 m20914 P00432,P00433              
5 m20915 P00433                     
6 m20925 P00434                     
7 m26943 P540554,P209332            
8 m26944 P00434,P00435,P00436,P00437
```

Comment: Ooh! I've just learned a new thing! Didn't know about separate rows. My clumsy workaround was unnecessary!

Comment: Didn't really contribute anything that yours didn't do better.